# Copy a cell to a merged cell while keeping hyperlink value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a cell content + its hyperlink to another cell (that's merged). I keep getting the "cannot do that to a merged cell" error when using the code below.

```
Worksheets("X").Cells(1, 1).copy Worksheets("Y").Cells(1 + 1, 30)
```

Comment: Well, you could remove the merge and then run your code... have you attempted to deconstruct your source cell and rebuild in the merged cell?  As stated from the error, you can't do that to a merged cell.

Comment: hmm I guess I can use a macro that does this... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on the *deconstruct* I suggested... source cell has 2 parts, the content and link:

```
Cells(1+1, 30) = Cells(1, 1)
Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add Cells(1+1, 30), Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

This does work for merged destination cells.